# How to prevent losing production data when changing my GraphQL schema in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

In my AWS Amplify project I am using a GraphQL API with several `@model` directives. Therefore, Amplify generated multiple DynamoDB tables in my AWS backend. Now, when removing such a `@model` or renaming it, the old DynamoDB table will be **permanently deleted with all the contained data**!

How can this be prevented to avoid production data by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your DynamoDB tables from being deleted you can set the `DeletionPolicy` to `Retain`. Unfortunately, Amplify does not do this by default.

Therefore, you can use the **custom GraphQL directive** `@retain` like this:

1. Install the transformer: `npm install --save graphql-retain-transformer`.
2. Edit `amplify/backend/api/<YOUR_API>/transform.conf.json` and append `"graphql-retain-transformer"` to the transformers field:

```
"transformers": [
    "graphql-retain-transformer"
]
```

3. In your `schema.graphql` file, append the `@retain` directive to all the `@model` types that you want to activate the Retain Deletion Policy for:

```
type Todo @model @retain {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String
}
```

**GitHub repository of the custom directive:** https://github.com/flogy/graphql-retain-transformer (please leave a ⭐️ if you like it )

**A more detailed blog post about it:** https://react-freelancer.ch/blog/amplify-retain-dynamodb-tables